# Nginx serve angular on sub path and php backend on subpath

Tags: php, angular, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have got an Nginx proxy (`domain.com`) - all requests are proxied to the nginx webserver in the docker container. On the docker container I have got a angular webapp (`domain.com/app`) and a php cms (Cockpit-CMS) (`domain.com/cms`).

I want to serve my angular application on `domain.com/app`, not `domain.com/app/`, and my php backend (Cockpit-CMS) under `domain.com/cms`, not `domain.com/cms/`.

Everytime I navigate to `domain.com/app`, it redirects me to `localhost:8888` (dockercontainer webserver port).

And I didn't get the cms to work on the subfolder.

This is the config on the docker container nginx server:

```
# Angular APP
location /app {
    alias /home/container/webroot/myAngularApp;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /app/index.html =404;
}

location /cms {
    root /home/container/webroot/cockpit-core;
    index index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /cms/index.php?$query_string;
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/home/container/tmp/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "upload_max_filesize = 100M \n post_max_size=100M";
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY "";
        fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
    }
}
```